# как импортировать отдельную функцию из модуля Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

При применении в новом файле функции from vozved_pomod import vozved_pomod1, также подтягивается функция def chisla(). Как сделать, чтоб в файле, в который происходит импорт, она не вызывалась, т.е. не просила ввести значения

```
def chisla():
    global x, y, z
    x = input('Введите число которое будете возводить в степень: ')
    y = input('Введите степень: ')
    z = input('Введите делитель по модулю: ')
chisla()

def vozved_pomod1():
    mas1 = list()
    dvoich = bin(int(y))
    mas = list(dvoich)
    del mas[0]
    del mas[0]
    mas = mas[::-1]
    # составление массива степеней
    for i in range(len(mas)):
        p = 0
        p = int(mas[i]) * 2 ** i
        mas1.append(p)
    res = 1
    # вычисление результата
    for i in range(len(mas1)):
        res = res * (int(x) ** mas1[i] % int(z))
    # еще раз по модулю из-за того, что перебирали поразрядно
    res = res % int(z)
    print('Результат работы (', int(x), '^', int(y), ') %', int(z), ' равен: ', res)

vozved_pomod1()
```

```
import math
from vozved_pomod import vozved_pomod1
def diffi():
    q = input('Введите простое число q: ')
diffi()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def chisla():
    global x, y, z
    x = input('Введите число которое будете возводить в степень: ')
    y = input('Введите степень: ')
    z = input('Введите делитель по модулю: ')


def vozved_pomod1():
    mas1 = list()
    dvoich = bin(int(y))
    mas = list(dvoich)
    del mas[0]
    del mas[0]
    mas = mas[::-1]
    # составление массива степеней
    for i in range(len(mas)):
        p = 0
        p = int(mas[i]) * 2 ** i
        mas1.append(p)
    res = 1
    # вычисление результата
    for i in range(len(mas1)):
        res = res * (int(x) ** mas1[i] % int(z))
    # еще раз по модулю из-за того, что перебирали поразрядно
    res = res % int(z)
    print('Результат работы (', int(x), '^', int(y), ') %', int(z), ' равен: ', res)

vozved_pomod1()
if __name__ == '__main__'
    chisla()
```

И

```
import math
from vozved_pomod import vozved_pomod1
def diffi():
    q = input('Введите простое число q: ')
diffi()
```

Comment: Код нужно пояснять, если вы хотите, чтобы за ваш ответ голосовали.

Comment: главное, чтобы автор разобрался)

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит, потому что вы вызываете функцию в вашем *модуле*.
Чтобы при импорте функции не вызывались используют конструкцию

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

Или можно просто убрать вызов функций в модуле.
В вашем примере нужно изменить файл `vozved_pomod`:

```
def chisla():
    global x, y, z
    x = input('Введите число которое будете возводить в степень: ')
    y = input('Введите степень: ')
    z = input('Введите делитель по модулю: ')
# убрал вызов

def vozved_pomod1():
    mas1 = list()
    dvoich = bin(int(y))
    mas = list(dvoich)
    del mas[0]
    del mas[0]
    mas = mas[::-1]
    # составление массива степеней
    for i in range(len(mas)):
        p = 0
        p = int(mas[i]) * 2 ** i
        mas1.append(p)
    res = 1
    # вычисление результата
    for i in range(len(mas1)):
        res = res * (int(x) ** mas1[i] % int(z))
    # еще раз по модулю из-за того, что перебирали поразрядно
    res = res % int(z)
    print('Результат работы (', int(x), '^', int(y), ') %', int(z), ' равен: ', res)

# убрал вызов
if __name__ == '__main__':
    chisla()
    vozved_pomod1()
```